# Subscribe to two topics MQTT in python script

Tags: python-3.x, mqtt

I have a python script that is tuned to a subject in MQTT, is it works fine.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt #import the client1
import time
import json
import requests

def on_log(client, userdata, level, buf) :
    #print("log: "+buf)
    k=0

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc) :
     if rc==0:
     print("connected ok")
else:
     print("not connected", rc)


def on_disconnect(client, userdata, flags, rc=0) :
    print("disconnect result code "+str(rc))


def on_message(client,userdata,msg) :
   global m_decode
   topic=msg.topic
   m_decode=str(msg.payload.decode("utf-8","ignore"))
   time.sleep(1)

   lora_s = str(m_decode)
   lora = {"lora_tram":lora_s}
   resp = requests.post('http://51.75.120.146/lora_tram_reception.php', data = lora)


broker_address="127.0.0.1:1883"
client = mqtt.Client("paca") #create new instance
client.on_connect=on_connect
client.on_disconnect=on_disconnect
client.on_log=on_log
client.on_message=on_message

print ("cnct to broker", broker_address)
client.connect("127.0.0.1", 1883, 60)
client.subscribe("gateway/a555b555c555d555/rx")
client.loop_forever()
```

And I would like to subscribe to another topic in the same time! Is it possible to do that ?

I try to add client.subscribe("gateway/new topic/rx") under :

```
client.subscribe("gateway/a555b555c555d555/rx")
```

And it look like working, but I'm not sure if it like that we code multiple topics.

Comment: FYI,you can check the comments and examples from the source code: https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/src/paho/mqtt/client.py#L1244

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also subscribe multiple topics in one MQTT subscribe message.

```
client.subscribe([("gateway/a555b555c555d555/rx", 0), ("gateway/new topic/rx", 0)])
```

https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python#subscribe-unsubscribe

Answer (score 3):

Calling subscribe multiple times with different topics is perfectly fine, you just need to work out which topic the message is from in the `on_message` callback.

You can do this with an if statement to check the `msg.topic` value and then process the message accordingly.

You should probably also move the calls to `subscribe` to the `on_connect` callback

Comment: thanks for your advice @hardillb, but i'm not understand why i should move the calls to      `subscribe`  !  you men i should add it in the     `def on_connect` ?

Comment: Because that will only try to subscribe if the connection succeeds, if you leave it where it and the client fails to connect for any reason it will then crash rather than try and reconnect.